# pythonnet clr: how to get the signature of a function/method?

Tags: python, clr, signature, python.net, method-signature

When importing a .NET library in Python with:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\foo.dll")
from foo import *

my_foo = Foo()
print(my_foo.my_method)
# <bound method 'my_method'>
```

I'd like to know the signature of the function (its parameters). This doesn't work:

```
from inspect import signature
print(signature(my_foo.my_method))
```

It fails with:

> ValueError: callable <bound method 'GroupStatusGet'> is not supported by signature

**Question: how to get the signature of a function on Python + .NET ?**

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in tools like `inspect` cannot be used to examine the signature of methods from .NET assemblies. This is because Python's introspection features work primarily with Python objects and their associated metadata, and .NET assemblies are fundamentally different types of objects. Therefore, `inspect.signature` will fail with a `ValueError` if you try to apply it to a .NET method.

You can use .NET's own reflection capabilities to inspect the signatures of its methods. Here's how you might do this using the `System.Reflection` namespace in .NET:

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\foo.dll")

from foo import *
from System.Reflection import BindingFlags

my_foo = Foo()

method_info = Foo.GetMethod('my_method', BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)

if method_info is None:
    print("Method 'my_method' not found.")
else:
    print(f"Found method 'my_method' in class 'Foo'.")
    params = method_info.GetParameters()
    if not params:
        print("The method 'my_method' does not take any parameters.")
    else:
        print(f"The method 'my_method' takes the following parameters:")
        for param in params:
            print(f"  Parameter name: {param.Name}")
            print(f"  Parameter type: {param.ParameterType}")
            print(f"  Parameter position: {param.Position}")
            print()
```

#### Edit #1

The code example will throw `AttributeError` as mentioned in the comments. The issue here is related to the reflection API. The method `GetMethod` is not an instance method, but a method from the .NET's `Type` class.

I've fixed the code (validated locally):

```
import clr
from System.Reflection import BindingFlags
from System import String
from System import Type

my_string = String("Hello, World!")
my_string_type = my_string.GetType()

method_info = my_string_type\
    .GetMethod('ToLower', BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, None, Type.EmptyTypes, None)

if method_info is None:
    print("Method 'ToLower' not found.")
else:
    print(f"Found method 'ToLower' in class '{my_string_type}'.")
    params = method_info.GetParameters()
    if not params:
        print("The method 'ToLower' does not take any parameters.")
    else:
        print(f"The method 'ToLower' takes the following parameters:")
        for param in params:
            print(f"  Parameter name: {param.Name}")
            print(f"  Parameter type: {param.ParameterType}")
            print(f"  Parameter position: {param.Position}")
            print()
```

Comment: Thanks but I get: `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'GetMethod'`. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Yup, you're right @Basj. I've fixed the example code, see edit #1.

Comment: Yes but how to apply this to any object's method @MustaphaHadid, such as `Foo` from `foo.dll`?

Comment: You just need to create a new object and call `GetType()` before invoking reflection methods (e.g., `.GetMethod(...)`). See lines 6 & 7.

Comment: Note that I set `Type.EmptyTypes` for the `types` parameter. This is because, in the case of the `ToLower` method, there are two overloaded methods: `ToLower()` and `ToLower(CultureInfo)`. Without specifying that parameter, an `AmbiguousMatchException` error would be thrown since `GetMethod(...)` wouldn't be certain which `ToLower` I'm referring to.